# Paste a value in a textbox on the second tab of a navigation form access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm quite new to VBA and I've been looking around but cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have made a navigation form (frmNavigation) with 3 buttons, each referring to a different form, let's call them frm1, frm2 and frm3. In the navigationform the control buttons to switch between tabs are all named differently (btn1, btn2, btn3), but the subform that shows either frm1, frm2, or frm3 has the same name: “NavigationSubform” (this shows a different form depending on which tab is clicked on, based on the 'navagation target name' referring to frm1, frm2 and frm3).

When I want to refer to a textbox (txtBox1) on form 1 (first tab) and insert a value i can do this by:

Forms!frmNavigation!NavigationSubform.Form!txtBox1.Value = "insert awesome text"

But how would I refer to txtbox10 on the second tab (frm2)? Just using the following does not work:

Forms!frmNavigation!NavigationSubform.Form!txtBox10.Value

You then get the error 2465 (can't find the field).

I’ve been trying many different things, but can’t seem to get it right. So how do I refer to a textbox on a different tab than the first one?

Help us much appreciated!

Comment: With a Navigation Form, only one of the forms is loaded at a time therefore when frm1 is active, frm2 cannot be referenced, period. Perhaps you should use a Tab control instead of Navigation Form.

Answer (score 0):

Only one subform can be loaded at once. So you've just got to break this process into two steps.

1. Store the value from txtBox1 somewhere outside of the NavigationSubforms (a textbox on the parent form with visible = no, a global variable or a table works).
2. In frm2's On Load event, set txtbox10 to be the value you stored.

Just note, that you will need to add conditions in the On Load event if you want to avoid that textbox being set to an empty string or a wrong value if you have a setup where your filter is changing.